# How to merge diffent layers to a bmp file?

Tags: javascript, python, photoshop, psd

I would like Photoshop to automatically execute the following task

1. get the icon on layers infomation: position width hight
2. extract diffent layers and merge them to a bmp file

i am familiar with python, but javascript is ok if it could do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do this on Photoshop, you need to record an action and apply it to any photo.

If you want to do this on Python, I do not know what API you want to use but the general process is to create a mask based on the position and size information from the icon image and, with bitwise operations, to merge it to the other layers. Then save it as a bmp file.

Here an example [Bitwise Operations in OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d0/d86/tutorial_py_image_arithmetics.html)

Comment: Click "Windows -> Actions" or Alt+F9 to open Action window, and click on "Create new action". Then automatically will start to record actions you do.

Comment: where is my action save place ?  I can not found the correpond file

Comment: It depends on your OS. Here is the list:

https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/kb/preference-file-names-locations-photoshop1.html